# 2 variables in a for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have two vectors that I would like to reference in a for loop, but each is of different lengths.

```
n=1:50
m=letters[1:14]
```

I tried a single loop to read it

```
for (i in c(11:22,24,25)){
    cat (paste(n[i],m[i],sep='\t'),sep='\n')
}
```

and ended up with:

```
11  k
12  l
13  m
14  n
15  NA
16  NA
17  NA
18  NA
19  NA
20  NA
21  NA
22  NA
24  NA
25  NA
```

but I would like to obtain:

```
11  a
12  b
13  c
...
25  n
```

is there a way to have a double variable declaration?

```
for (i in c(11:22,24,25) and j in 1:14){
    cat (paste(n[i],m[j],sep='\t'),sep='\n')
}
```

or something similar to get the result I want?

Comment: You don't need a `for` loop.   `paste(n[c(11:22, 24:25)], m[1:14])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No there isn't. But you can do this:

```
ind_j <- c(11:22,24,25)
ind_k <- 1:14
for (i in seq_along(ind_j)){
  cat (paste(n[ind_j[i]],m[ind_k[i]],sep='\t'),sep='\n')
}
```

Of course, it's *very* probable that you shouldn't use a `for` loop for your actual problem.

Comment: that is a great solution, and it fits in nicely!

Answer (score 0):

If you want `m` to start over when it has reached the end, you can take advantage of recycling in R.

```
cat(paste(n, m, sep='\t', collapse='\n'), '\n')
```

When the end of `m` is reached, it will start over until all elements of `n` have been iterated over. If you need this in a loop, replace `cat` with a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

your problem lies in assigning the values to i in `for (i in c(11:22,24,25)` - this assigns the values 11,12,13,14,15 .... to i.
then you want to get the values of m[i]. 
but remember: m[i] has only 1..14 items so for item 15 and above - you'll get NAs

maybe this is what you wanted - there are more robust answers here and @Roland's is far better but imho - this fixes your problem without changing **your initial approach**

```
for (i in c(1:12,14,15)){cat (paste(n[i],m[i],sep='\t'),sep='\n')}
```

if you just subtract 10 from your sequence - the indexing problem will go away and u'll get

```
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   d
5   e
6   f
7   g
8   h
9   i
10  j
11  k
12  l
14  n
15  o
```